# successful paypal api call is not showing up in the sandbox

Tags: api, paypal, payment, sandbox

Hi I'm a little perplexed.  I'm making a paypal api call with sandbox credentials.  The return ACK is: success.  When i go to either payer or business sandbox account no transactions have been processed.  I debuged through and looks like i'm populating all the fields, plus i would think if some fields are missing the error would've been thrown.  Here is the code I'm using.

.....

```
APIProfile apiProfile = ProfileFactory.createSignatureAPIProfile();
                    apiProfile.setAPIUsername(paypalAccount.getApiLogin());
                    apiProfile.setAPIPassword(paypalAccount.getApiPassword());
                    apiProfile.setSignature(paypalAccount.getApiSignature());
                    apiProfile.setEnvironment(paypalAccount.getApiEnvironment());

                    // caller
                    NVPCallerServices callerServices = new NVPCallerServices();
                    callerServices.setAPIProfile(apiProfile);

                    // encoder
                    NVPEncoder encoder = new NVPEncoder();
                    encoder.add(METHOD, METHOD_VALUE);
                    encoder.add(RETURNURL, paypalAccount.getReturnUrl());
                    encoder.add(CANCELURL, paypalAccount.getCancelUrl());
                    encoder.add(CURRENCYCODE, CURRENCYCODE_VALUE);
                    encoder.add(PAYMENTACTION, PAYMENTACTION_VALUE);
                    encoder.add(AMT, payment.getPaymentOrder().getPrice().toString());
                    encoder.add(L_NAME0, L_NAME0_VALUE);
                    encoder.add(L_AMT0, payment.getPaymentOrder().getPrice().toString());

                    // call
                    String NVPRequest = encoder.encode();
                    String NVPResponse = callerServices.call(NVPRequest);
                    NVPDecoder decoder = new NVPDecoder();
                    decoder.decode(NVPResponse);

                    String ack = decoder.get(ACK);
                    payment.setPaymentTransaction(decoder.get(TOKEN));
```

......

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using express checkout you need to make 3 calls:

- SetExpressCheckout (response with a token)
- GetExpressCheckout
- DoExpressCheckout

Once ‘DoExpressCheckout’ passes you should be able to see a transaction logged in your sandbox buyer and merchant accounts.

Have a look at: https://www.x.com/devzone/excerpts/chapter-2-express-checkout